# Are there sigma-algebras of cardinality $\kappa>2^{\aleph_0}$ with countable cofinality?

Tags: measure-theory, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, set-theory

A standard homework in measure theory textbooks asks the student to prove that there are not countably infinite $\sigma$-algebras. The only proof that I know is via a contradiction argument which yields no estimate on the minimum cardinality of an infinite $\sigma$-algebra.

Given an a set $X$ of infinite cardinality $\kappa$, the $\sigma$-algebra of all co-countable subsets of $X$ is of cardinality <del>$2^\kappa$</del> $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$. This example doesn't tell me whether there are $\sigma$-algebras of cardinality below $2^{\aleph_0}$, if I don't assume the Continuum Hypothesis.

My question is as the title says: Are there $\sigma$-algebras of every uncountable cardinality?

Edit: The combined answer with Stephen, Matthew proves that the cardinality of a $\sigma$-algebra is necessarily at least $2^{\aleph_0}$. Further, for each cardinality $\kappa\ge 2^{\aleph_0}$ with uncountable cofinality, the $\sigma$-algebra of countable (or cocountable) subsets of a set $X$ with cardinality $\kappa$, is of cardinality $\kappa$.

What is left is whether for $\kappa\ge 2^{\aleph_0}$ with $cf(\kappa)=\aleph_0$ are there $\sigma$-algebras of cardinality $\kappa$. (I changed the title to reflect this.)

Thanks Stephen, Matthew, Apollo, for the combined work!

Comment: It seems to me that Matthew's answer contradicts your claim in the second paragraph, and that Matthew is right.

Comment: @Harald: As Griffeth pointed out, it seems that Matthew has omitted in his calculation those subsets which are countably infinite. 

Comment: Dear Harald, 

Well, what about the sigma algebra of all countable or co-countable subsets of a countable set?  Wouldn't Matthew's argument "prove" that it has countable cardinality?

Best,
Stephen

Comment: Argh! I shall never again try to do mathematics when surrounded by loud conversation. I used to be able to do that, but now it seems I can't maintain my concentration in such circumstances. Oh well.

Comment: "For each cardinality $\kappa\ge 2^{\aleph_0}$ with uncountable cofinality, the $\sigma$-algebra of countable (or cocountable) subsets of a set $X$ with cardinality $\kappa$, is of cardinality $\kappa$"? I couldn't figure out why this is true: if $\beth_{\omega}<\kappa<\beth_{\omega+1}$ and $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)>\aleph_0$, then $\kappa^{\aleph_0}\ge\beth_{\omega}^{\aleph_0}=\beth_{\omega+1}>\kappa$, no? Have I mistaken something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm really not used to thinking about this sort of question (which is why I'm giving it a shot...) but here goes.

Given a $\sigma$-algebra $A$ of subsets of a set $X$, assume that $A$ is infinite.  Then $A$ is a poset, with inclusion as the order relation.  Apply Zorn's lemma to the poset $P$ of all linearly ordered subsets of $A$ to conclude that there is a maximal linearly ordered subset of $A$; since $A$ is infinite this implies there is an infinite chain $S_1 \subset S_2 \subset \cdots$ of elements of $A$.  The pairwise differences $S_{i+1}-S_{i}$ are pairwise disjoint and generate a $\sigma$-subalgebra of $A$ of size at least the size of the power set of $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$.  So any infinite $\sigma$-algebra is at least that big.

Edit: Actually, this combined Matthew's argument below  *almost* finishes the problem: if the cardinality of X is at least that of the power set of $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, then the $\sigma$-algebra of countable or cocountable sets in $X$ has cardinality $X$ *if $X$ is not of countable cofinality*. So a cardinal number is the cardinality of a sigma algebra <strike>exactly</strike> if it is at least the cardinality of the continuum (no CH needed) *and not of countable cofinality*.

Comment: So this would seem to suggest that it's not possible to get a cardinality between $\aleph_0$ and $2^\aleph_0$...

Comment: Right... but I don't know about which larger cardinals are achievable.

Comment: A small nitpick: the set of negative integers is infinite and linearly ordered but it'll take quite a lot of effort to extract an infinite increasing chain out of it.

Comment: Dear fedja,

Yes, but fortunately A is closed under taking complements!  I have to admit that I was unsure (for at least 2 reasons) what the right level of detail was here.

Best,
Stephen

Comment: Dear Matthew, 

Oops!  I should have been paying more attention.  I guess combining what we've written finishes off the problem (unless I've made a mistake somewhere...) 

Best,
Stephen

Comment: @Stephan Matthew did not claim that the cardinality of the collection of countable subsets of X is of cardinality equal to X. In fact when $|X|=\kappa$ is of countable cofinality, then the sigma-algebra is of cardinality $\kappa^{\aleph_0}$ which is strictly larger than $\kappa$.

Comment: Dear Colin,

Perhaps I am mistaken, but is it not true that *every* cardinal at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ is of uncountable cofinality?

That's all we need to finish up.

Best,
Stephen

Comment: Dear Griffeth, $\aleph_\omega$ has countable cofinality. If CH is true, then $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1<\aleph_\omega$. 

Comment: Oops!  You're quite right.


Comment: Take $\kappa=\aleph_\omega$. $cf(\aleph_\omega)=\aleph_0$ does satisfy the inequality on Wikipedia. Since $2^{\aleph_\omega}$ is uncountable. Take a look at http://www.ii.com/math/cardinals/ on Singular Cardinals.

Comment: Actually, I'm still confused: wikipedia claims that the cofinality of $2^{aleph_0}$ is uncountable.  What's going on?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/König%27s_theorem_(set_theory)

Comment: $2^{\aleph_0}$ is different from $\aleph_\omega$. Maybe you are thinking that $cf(\kappa)$ is an increasing function in $\kappa$? (which it is not)

Comment: That wasn't what I was thinking... wikipedia claims in 2 different places that $\kappa<cf(2^\kappa)$.  Apply this with $\kappa=\aleph_0$.  

Comment: Yes. You have just proved that $2^{\aleph_0}$ has uncountable cofinality. Still, that does not exclude the possibility of cardinals larger than $2^{\aleph_0}$ which has countable cofinality.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Weird.  

Answer (score 10):

A Boolean algebra is $\sigma$-complete if every countable subset has a least upper bound
and a greatest lower bound.  Every $\sigma$-algebra is a $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra.
Every (infinite) $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra $B$ satisfies $|B|^{\aleph_0}=|B|$.
(I am almost certain that a proof of this fact is in the Handbook of Boolean Algebras, Volume 1.)
Since for every infinite cardinal $\kappa$, $\kappa<\kappa^{\text{cf}(\kappa)}$,
there is no infinite $\sigma$-algebra of some size $\kappa$ of cofinality $\aleph_0$.

Something stronger is actually true:
By a result of Koppelberg [Boolean algebras as unions of chains of subalgebras, Algebra Universalis, Vol. 7 (1977), 195-203], no $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra is the union of
a countable increasing chain of proper subalgebras.  This also implies that the
size of a $\sigma$-algebra cannot be of countable cofinality.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Yeah, this is nonsense!  So really $|S|=|X|^{|\mathbb N|}=|X|^{\aleph_0}$.

Let X be a set of uncountable cardinality.  Let S be the collection of countable or cocountable subsets of X.  Then $X\in S$, clearly $S$ is closed under taking complements, and S is easily seen to be closed under countable unions.

Every co-countable set corresponds to a countable set, so the cardinality of S is equal to the cardinality of the collection of countable subsets of X, say C.  We can write C as the countable union of subsets of X of size $1,2,3,\cdots$.  But the collection of subsets of X of size n has cardinality |X| for any n, and so we conclude that S has size |X| as well.

So, it seems you can find a sigma algebra of any uncountable cardinality.  Or did I make a mistake?

Comment: I don't understand where the countably infinite subsets of $X$ fit into your countable union (they don't have size $n$ for any integer $n$).  Am I being dense?

Comment: So, in fact, we get cardinality $|X|^{\aleph_0}$.  And, examining the argument, we see that ANY uncountable sigma-algebra is at least this, so has cardinal at least ${\alpha_0}^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.  Thus, if CH fails, then the answer to the original question is NO.

Comment: This argument doesn't work.  The set of countable subsets of a cardinal $\kappa$ will be of size $\kappa^\omega$ which will be equal to $2^\omega \kappa$ for $\kappa$ with uncountable cofinality (and hence $>\kappa$ for any $\kappa<2^\omega$.  For $\kappa$ of countable cofinality $\kappa^\omega>\kappa$.  So in all of these cases your construction fails.  However, for $\kappa$ of uncountable cofinality you will get a $\sigma$-algebra of cardinality $\kappa$.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I did indeed make a mistake.  Hopefully the edit shows this...

Comment: No, the conclusion is $|X|^{\aleph_0}$, not $2^{|X|}$.

Comment: Dear me...  Now it's right.